# stop_forward_pass in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

let's imagine that Tensorflow graph is consist of two parallel branches that have a common start and common end. In some point, I want to tell Tensorflow to stop disable computations on one branch. In other words stop forward and backward passes.  For the backward pass we have  stop_gradient op. But what for the forward pass, how to disable it? If this is not implemented now, please give me hints how can I create such op?

Comment: Does the "end" depend on both the parallel branches? If yes, it is impossible to do so.

Comment: @Priyatham  Yes depends on both, why is not possible? I know how to do this mathematically so this should be possible :) Maybe currently there is no such op but what is the problem to implement it?

Comment: how exactly does the end depend on the branches? Specifically, if `out = f(branch1, branch2)` what is `f`?

Comment: let say for simplicity it is addition: out = branch1 + branch2

Comment: How can you compute `out` when you don't know what `branch2` is?

Comment: if we are disabling  branch2  out=branch1 + lastBranch2 value. Or out = branch1 + 0. both are accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the discussion we had you can do something like this:

```
out = f(branch1, tf.cond(should_disable, lambda: last_branch2_value, lambda: branch2))
```

Here `should_disbale` is a `bool` that determines if `branch2` is computed or not. Note that `tf.cond()` is "differentiable" meaning that TensorFlow is smart enough to not do backward pass through `branch2` if `should_disbale` is `True`

See the docs for [tf.cond](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard0/tf.cond.md)  for more details.

Comment: Do you think `tf.cond()` is differentiable if the `bool` consists of a tf random number generator and a comparison operator?